# Is there a python module for identifying the source of a built in function?

Tags: python, built-in

Is it possible to get the source of a built in function using something like the inspect module? Say, if I entered the value of print the return value would be something like "source = bltinmodule.c, builtin_print".

```
import inspect
import builtins

print_source = inspect.getsource(builtins.print)

print(print_source)

# TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got builtin_function_or_method
```

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d384813ff18b33280a90b6d2011654528a2b6ad1/Python/bltinmodule.c